# Sending email via Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, email

I'm trying to create a contact form. I am using Spring Boot 3.0.0. and Thymeleaf. Everything runs on localhost. I get an unexpected error when I want to send a message:

`javax.mail.Provider: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPProvider not a subtype java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.mail.Provider: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPProvider not a subtype`

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Message class:

```
public class MessageInfoDto {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String text;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MessageInfoController {
    MessageInfoService messageInfoService;

    public MessageInfoController(MessageInfoService messageInfoService) {
        this.messageInfoService = messageInfoService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/contact")
    public String emialForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", new MessageInfoDto());
        return "contact";
    }

    @PostMapping("/send")
    public String getMessage(MessageInfoDto message) {
        messageInfoService.sendEmail(message);
        return "redirect:/contact";
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class MessageInfoService {
    private final JavaMailSender mailSender;
    @Value("${spring.mail.username}")
    private String owner;

    public MessageInfoService(JavaMailSender mailSender) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }

    public void sendEmail(MessageInfoDto message) {
        SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
        simpleMailMessage.setTo(owner);
        simpleMailMessage.setFrom(message.getEmail());
        simpleMailMessage.setText(message.getText());
        simpleMailMessage.setSubject("New Message");
        simpleMailMessage.setReplyTo(message.getEmail());
        mailSender.send(simpleMailMessage);
    }
}
```

HTML(contact.html):

```
<body>
<main class="main-content" layout:fragment="content">
  <h2 class="list-heading">Send us a message</h2>
  <form action="#" th:action="@{/send}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="mc-form" th:object="${message}">
    <label for="name">Your Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" th:field="*{name}" required>
    <label for="email">Your e-mail</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="e-mail" th:field="*{email}">
    <label for="message">Your message</label>
    <textarea id="message" rows="10" th:field="*{text}"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
  </form>
</main>
</body>
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username: 10*****@gmail.com
    password: [genereted password]
    properties:
      smtp:
        auth: true
        starttles:
          enable: true
          required: true
```

Please help, I've been googling this since yesterday and couldn't find an answer.

I've also tried with `javax.mail-api`.

Comment: For Spring Boot 3, you probably need the jakarta (not javax) library <dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.2/reference/html/integration.html#mail for details.

Comment: still the same. I thought it was a google authorization problem, I changed my mail to another one with a different domain but it keeps showing the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need this, please remove it.

`<dependency>`
        `<groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>`
        `<artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>`
        `<version>1.6.2</version>`
    `</dependency>`

2. Check MailSender import

USE `import org.springframework.mail.MailSender;`

NOT `import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;`

3. spring-boot-starter-mail will create default MailSender , you don't create it (MailSender), just use `@Autowired private MailSender mailSender;`

Hello.java

```
package com.example.demo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
//import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.MailSender;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController

public class Hello {
    @Autowired
    private MailSender mailSender;
    @RequestMapping("/sendMail")
    public String sendConfirmationEmail() {
        SimpleMailMessage msg = new SimpleMailMessage();
        msg.setTo("aaa@localhost");
        msg.setSubject("Testing from Spring Boot");
        msg.setText("Hello World from Spring Boot Email");
        mailSender.send(msg);
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

I am test ok in my simple test project.

`curl http://localhost:8080/sendMail`

And I use FakeSmtp jar to my fake mail server.

my spring boot 3 pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-mail</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo-mail</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

MY application.properties

```
spring.mail.host=localhost
spring.mail.port=2525
spring.mail.username=demo@localhost
spring.mail.password=demopassword

spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.transport.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtps.quitwait=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
```

DemoMailApplication.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoMailApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoMailApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

- DemoMailApplication.java
- Hello.java
- application.properties
- pom.xml

---

## Spring Boot 2.7.x send Mail with  attachments

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

### DemoApplication.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

### Hello.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.mail.MailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.io.File;

@RestController

public class Hello {
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender;
    @RequestMapping("/sendMail")
    public String sendConfirmationEmail() throws MessagingException {
        MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
        helper.setTo("test@host.com");
        helper.setText("Check out this image!");
        FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(new File("/YourAttachmentFile/Example.jpg"));
        helper.addAttachment("CoolImage.jpg", file);
        mailSender.send(message);
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

### application.properties

```
spring.mail.host=localhost
spring.mail.port=2525
spring.mail.username=demo@localhost
spring.mail.password=demopassword
spring.mail.properties[mail.smtp.connectiontimeout]=5000
spring.mail.properties[mail.smtp.timeout]=3000
spring.mail.properties[mail.smtp.writetimeout]=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.transport.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtps.quitwait=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
```

### Package

```
mvn clean package
```

### Run

```
cd target
java -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

### Test

```
curl http://localhost:8080/sendMail
```

**You can use FakeSmtp as Dummy Mail Server**

## REFERENCE

Example Code is copy from spring-boot-reference-2.7.8.pdf ( **11.4. Sending Email** -> TIP See the **reference documentation** ) -> https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.25/reference/html/integration.html#mail (**6.2.1. Sending Attachments and Inline Resources**)

Comment: Hi there, I am having this same error, but unfortunately I can't avoid using JavaMailSender, as I need to be able to send attachments. Do you have another way around this?

Comment: @S Hornby, (1) Using JavaMailSender or MailSender should be able to send letters and attach attachments. (2) Are you using Spring Boot 3.x or Spring Boot 2.x?

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.7.

Comment: @S Hornby , I Update My Answer, Add `Spring Boot 2.7.x send Mail with attachments`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your update. I'm afraid you may have misunderstood what I was saying, though. Your initial response said NOT to use JavaMailSender, and I commented on that saying I needed to use it in order to send attachments. Your updated response shows you using JavaMailSender.

Regardless, I was doing basically the same thing as what you posted, though I didn't have as many properties in the configuration. I added them and still got the same error: "javax.mail.Provider: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPProvider not a subtype"

Comment: @S Hornby, (1) My test case is to use the minimum settings as long as the basic needs can be met, it is enough and acceptable for me. (2) Please use my example first, don't add it to your original code. My example, I have tested, pom.xml is enough and can send email with attachment. (3) Your error message `javax.mail.Provider: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPProvider not a subtype`, should come from your other code and settings, not from my sample code and settings. Because you Without providing your pom.xml and your code, I can't judge, I can only judge that you may be missing some dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

```
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;

public void sendEmail(){
JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
mailSender.setPort(587);
mailSender.setUsername("yourEmail@example.com");
mailSender.setPassword("yourPassword");
SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
message.setFrom("sender@example.com");
message.setTo("receiver@example.com");
message.setSubject("Test Email");
message.setText("This is a test email sent using Spring Boot");
mailSender.send(message);
}
```

Comment: Still the same Problem

Comment: For gmail latest it is not allowing plain password to be used in external application. may have to switched to use Session