# Send Spring Boot simple email

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to send an email using Spring Boot. However, I get the error below in the console. I try the whole thing with GMX as email provider

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
> nested exception is:
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate); message exceptions (1) are:
> Failed message 1: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
> nested exception is:
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)] with root cause
>
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol
> is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)

Main Code:

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;


private void sendMail() {
    
     SimpleMailMessage msg = new SimpleMailMessage();
     msg.setTo("to_1@gmail.com", "to_2@gmail.com", "to_3@yahoo.com");

     msg.setSubject("Testing from Spring Boot");
     msg.setText("Hello World \n Spring Boot Email");

     javaMailSender.send(msg);
   
}
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

application.properties file:

```
 spring.mail.protocol=smtp
 spring.mail.host=mail.gmx.net
 spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.trust=mail.gmx.net
 spring.mail.port=587
 spring.mail.username=XYZ@gmx.de
 spring.mail.password=xyz
 # Other properties
 spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
 spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
 spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
 spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
 # TLS , port 587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

Comment: For starters start by removed the `javax.mail` and `spring-context-support` dependencies those are already part of `spring-boot-starter-mail`. You enabled SSL but apparently have a restricted set of ciphers in your JDK to use. Without knowing the cipher or the underlying error this will be impossible to guess the fix. But doe you really need the SSL stuff?

Comment: Reference  this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74694051/sending-email-via-spring-boot/74750259#74750259, my answer

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
```

with

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=10000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=10000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=10000
```

Comment: So your solution is to simply double the timeouts, correct? Maybe you can [edit] your question and explain how that solves the problem?

Comment: This will never help solve the problem